# Como lograr efecto de sombra en Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]
Este es el efecto q deseo lograr

Pd: ya he intentando con gradientes pero no consigo el efecto deseado.

```
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.1" EndPoint="1,0.10" Opacity=".4" >
 <GradientStop Color="#7c7c7c" Offset="0.0" />
 <GradientStop Color="#D1D1D1" Offset="0.040" />
 <GradientStop Color="#D1D1D1" Offset="0.10" />
 <GradientStop Color="#D1D1D1" Offset="1.0" />
</LinearGradientBrush> </Controls:Tile.Background>
```

Comment: Si agregas tu codigo actual podemos partir de ahi y brindarte una mejor respuesta

Comment: <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.1" EndPoint="1,0.10"  Opacity=".4" >

                    <GradientStop Color="#7c7c7c" Offset="0.0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#D1D1D1" Offset="0.040" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#D1D1D1" Offset="0.10" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#D1D1D1" Offset="1.0" />
                
                    
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Controls:Tile.Background>
          
       este es el codigo que tengo pero no logro el efecto deseado

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza `DropShadowEffect` que crea una sombra sobre un elemento.

Aqui un ejemplo de uso:

```
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="White" Panel.ZIndex="1">
        <Grid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" RenderingBias="Quality" Color="#ccc" ShadowDepth="5" Direction="5" />
        </Grid.Effect>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="#ccc"></Grid>
</Grid>
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias sos de mucha ayuda

Comment: Lo probaste? Te funciono?

Comment: También funciona si reemplaza DropShadowEffect por DropShadowBitmapEffect